# get list item which have count more than specific number by Python

Tags: python, list

I have nested list :

```
   ip[0] = ['23:30:42.476071', '55729', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034568', -1]
   ip[1] = ['23:30:43.110194', '20442', '201.20.49.239.80', '192.168.98.138.49341', '364925831', '562034569']
    ip[2] = ['23:30:43.110290', '55730', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', -1, '5840']
    ip[3] = ['23:30:43.170344', '55731', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034569:562034972', '364925832']
    ip[4] = ['23:30:43.170918', '20443', '201.20.49.239.80', '192.168.98.138.49341', -1, '64240']
    ip[5] = ['23:30:44.022511', '20444', '201.20.49.239.80', '192.168.98.138.49341', '364925832:364925978', '562034972']
```

I want get index and sublist from my original list that have ip[i][2] = 192.168.98.138

for the above list I want get :

```
    ip[0] = ['23:30:42.476071', '55729', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034568', -1]
    ip[2] = ['23:30:43.110290', '55730', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', -1, '5840']
    ip[3] = ['23:30:43.170344', '55731', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034569:562034972', '364925832']
```

Comment: You use indexes 1-5, but Python lists are 0-indexed. Is that in error?

Comment: Could you provide a more clear example showing what you have (i.e. the whole original list) and what exactly you want the output to be?

Comment: When you say "more than 3" -- you mean more than 3 elements? The example data you provide does not in any way indicate this behavior. Please ensure that your problem description and your sample data are consistent with each other.

Comment: Oh, you mean ip[i][2] == ip[0][2]. Again, please be careful to be clear.

Comment: @Charles sorry for my mistake :( But I am newbie in python programing and I want it fast so I am confused (and Also I am bad in english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return results where `ip[i][2] == ip[0][2]` use a list comprehension:

```
result = [ d for d in ip if d[2] == ip[0][2] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for clarifying. Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> ip = [['23:30:42.476071', '55729', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034568', -1], 
['23:30:43.110194', '20442', '201.20.49.239.80', '192.168.98.138.49341', '364925831', '562034569'],
['23:30:43.110290', '55730', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', -1, '5840'],
['23:30:43.170344', '55731', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034569:562034972', '364925832'],
['23:30:43.170918', '20443', '201.20.49.239.80', '192.168.98.138.49341', -1, '64240'],
['23:30:44.022511', '20444', '201.20.49.239.80', '192.168.98.138.49341', '364925832:364925978', '562034972']]

>>> needle = ip[0][2]
>>> [item for item in ip if item[2]==needle]
[['23:30:42.476071', '55729', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034568', -1], 
['23:30:43.110290', '55730', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', -1, '5840'], 
['23:30:43.170344', '55731', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034569:562034972', '364925832']]
```

Comment: Not that it's clear, but I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: sorry for my mistake, tanx for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
[addr for addr in ip if addr[2].startswith("192.168.98.138"]
```

which is the same as, though much neater than:

```
addrs = []
for addr in ip:
    if addr[2].startswith("192.168.98.138"):
        addrs.append(addr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get both the index and the sublist (according to what you describe), then the following might work:

```
>>> print [(index, x) for index, x in enumerate(ip) if x[2] == ip[0][2]]
[(0, ['23:30:42.476071', '55729', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034568', -1]), (2, ['23:30:43.110290', '55730', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', -1, '5840']), (3, ['23:30:43.170344', '55731', '192.168.98.138.49341', '201.20.49.239.80', '562034569:562034972', '364925832'])]
```